# Find number of columns in csv file

Tags: python, csv

My program needs to read csv files which may have 1,2 or 3 columns, and it needs to modify its behaviour accordingly. Is there a simple way to check the number of columns without "consuming" a row before the iterator runs? The following code is the most elegant I could manage, but I would prefer to run the check before the for loop starts:

```
import csv
f = 'testfile.csv'
d = '\t'

reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=d)
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 1: fields = len(row)
    if len(row) != fields:
        raise CSVError("Number of fields should be %s: %s" % (fields,str(row)))
    if fields == 1:
        pass
    elif fields == 2:
        pass
    elif fields == 3:
        pass
    else:
        raise CSVError("Too many columns in input file.")
```

**Edit:** I should have included more information about my data. If there is only one field, it must contain a name in scientific notation. If there are two fields, the first must contain a name, and the second a linking code. If there are three fields, the additional field contains a flag which specifies whether the name is currently valid. Therefore if any row has 1, 2 or 3 columns, all must have the same.

Comment: better use `fields` instead of `rows` .

Comment: @MarcodeWit thanks, it should of course be `fields`! I also agreed with your point that not all rows necessarily have the same number of fields. In this case I've decided it should raise an exception if such a row is encountered.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

> itertools.tee(iterable[, n=2])
>   Return n independent iterators from a
>   single iterable.

eg.

```
reader1, reader2 = itertools.tee(csv.reader(f, delimiter=d))
columns = len(next(reader1))
del reader1
for row in reader2:
    ...
```

Note that it's important to delete the reference to `reader1` when you are finished with it - otherwise `tee` will have to store all the rows in memory in case you ever call `next(reader1)` again

Answer (score 21):

This seems to work as well:

```
import csv

datafilename = 'testfile.csv'
d = '\t'
f = open(datafilename,'r')

reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=d)
ncol = len(next(reader)) # Read first line and count columns
f.seek(0)              # go back to beginning of file
for row in reader:
    pass #do stuff
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a simple way like this:

```
with open('./testfile.csv', 'r') as csv:
     first_line = csv.readline()
     your_data = csv.readlines()

ncol = first_line.count(',') + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

What happens if the user provides you with a CSV file with fewer columns? Are default values used instead?

If so, why not extend the row with null values instead?

```
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=d)
for row in reader:
    row += [None] * (3 - len(row))
    try:
        foo, bar, baz = row
    except ValueError:
        # Too many values to unpack: too many columns in the CSV
        raise CSVError("Too many columns in input file.")
```

Now bar and baz will at least be `None` and the exception handler will take care of any rows longer than 3 items.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that each row must have consistently the same data in each field, but the data is difficult to validate.

Comment: I don't see how my approach places any more consistency constraints than just testing for the length of the first row. Besides, you didn't tell us much about your data; hence my answer starts with a question.

Comment: you are right, I've edited my question to include more about the data, and also to include a consistency check per row.

Answer (score -1):

I would rebuild it as follows ( if the file is not too big ):

```
import csv
f = 'testfile.csv'
d = '\t'

reader = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter=d))
fields = len( reader[0] )
for row in reader:
    if fields == 1:
        pass
    elif fields == 2:
        pass
    elif fields == 3:
        pass
    else:
        raise CSVError("Too many columns in input file.")
```

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : That's why I started with the warning about filesize. The `list` function copies everything over from the iterator, so only small csv files are suitable.