# How to read massive csv files with Python inside Cinema4D?

Tags: python, cinema-4d

I have a bunch of csv files where each column holds a value representing the angle of each of the Canadarm2's 7 segments. The largest file contains values for every second of a 5 hour mission and is 30 megs!

I've written this python script below in C4D's Script Manager that reads data from the csv and creates keyframes every second where the segments are rotated according to the angle data.

The script works well on small files up to about 1 meg in size but I get the dreaded "Cinema4D has stopped responding" alert or it just sits there silently with apparently nothing happening when I try to process larger files.

Has anyone had any experience with something like this? Might more memory than my 12 gigs help? If I could process say 30 minutes of data at a time inside C4D I'd have a winner.

```
memLog=''
record = 0
frame=0
path='/Users/...'
filename = path + '30minutes_3meg.csv'
fileobj = open(filename, 'r')

rowcount=0    
for row in fileobj:
    rowcount=rowcount+1
    if rowcount>1:
        ar = row.split(',')
        colcount=0
        for angle in ar:
            if colcount == 0:
                log=angle
                if log==memLog:
                    record=0
                else:
                    record=1
                    print log
                    frame=frame+1

                memLog=log

            if colcount == 2:
                if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'SR','r',angle)
            elif colcount == 4:
                 if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'SY','r',angle)
            elif colcount == 6:
                 if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'SP','r',angle)
            elif colcount == 8:
                if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'EP','h',angle)  
            elif colcount == 10:
                if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'WP','h',angle)  
            elif colcount == 12:
                if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'WY','h',angle)  
            elif colcount == 14:
                if record==1:
                    rotate(frame,'WR','h',angle)  

            colcount=colcount+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) which might make things easier.

If you're running into memory problems, I'd suggest doing a forced garbage collection. You do `import gc` and then in the loop, a `gc.collect()`. It's probably not required every loop, and would even slow things down if done too frequently. You could keep a counter variable (`rowcount` would do) and do it less frequently (every 10,000 loops, say. Experiment.). Consider adding a print statement indicating the collection happening and the row number. That way you can tell if the script is still running or if it has locked up.

```
if rowcount % 10000 == 0:
    print 'collecting', rowcount
    gc.collect()
```

If you can install external Python modules, you could also try using [Pandas to load the csv file](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv). It probably performs better for very large files, but you might have to specify a chunksize if you're still running out of memory.

Comment: Garbage collection allows me to now process and hour long animation without running out of memory. That's plenty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, the easiest way to use the file opener for parsing is [with](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) :

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fileobj:
```

Next, Python has a native library for [csv (called csv)](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907):

So to put it together (adapted from the link above and from [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310549/1449249)):

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as fileobj:

    filereader = csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter=',')
    colcount = len(next(filereader)) #Reads the first line and gets length
    if colcount == 0:
        record = 0
    else:
        record = 1 
    for row in filereader: 
        ar = row.split(',') #Split the row
        print (ar2) #prints out all of the rows 
        frame = colcount + 1 #Warning this will make an even column an odd number
        memLog = ar[colcount - 1]
        angle = ar[colcount - 1]
        if colcount == 2:
            if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'SR','r',angle)
        elif colcount == 4:
             if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'SY','r',angle)
        elif colcount == 6:
             if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'SP','r',angle)
        elif colcount == 8:
            if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'EP','h',angle)  
        elif colcount == 10:
            if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'WP','h',angle)  
        elif colcount == 12:
            if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'WY','h',angle)  
        elif colcount == 14:
            if record==1:
                rotate(frame,'WR','h',angle)
```

Sidenote: If you find out that you're doing this alot, may I suggest [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?  It will simplify the process and it can handle a lot of data.

---